# Getting detail with the click of a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, onclick, react-bootstrap

I am practising react and I am trying to get Name and category of an iten when I click on a button next to it. I use map method to render all the array objects into a react-bootstrap table and each item has a button next to it. I have tried filter metthod but I could not really get it done with that. Below is my code:

```
const ModalPractice = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const food = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'rice',
      category: 'grain',
      image: 'images/rice.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'beans',
      category: 'grain and protein',
      image: 'images/beans.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'amala',
      category: 'swallow',
      image: 'images/amala.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Oat',
      category: 'cereals',
      image: 'images/oat.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'coke',
      category: 'soft drink',
      image: 'images/coke.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'banana',
      category: 'fruit',
      image: 'images/banana.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: 'okra',
      category: 'vegetable',
      image: 'images/okra.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: 'yam',
      category: 'tuber',
      image: 'images/yam.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: 'palm oil',
      category: 'fat',
      image: 'images/palmoil.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      name: 'orange',
      category: 'fruit',
      image: 'images/orange.jpg',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>{food.map((list) => list.name)}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>{food.map((list) => list.category)}</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant='secondary' onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant='primary' onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>

      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Food Name</th>
            <th>Food Category</th>
            <th>Image</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {food.map((list) => (
            <tr className='align-middle' key={list.id}>
              <td>{list.id}</td>
              <td>{list.name}</td>
              <td>{list.category}</td>
              <td>
                <img alt='' src={list.image} width='100' height='100' />
              </td>
              <td>
                <Button variant='primary' onClick={handleShow}>
                  Detail
                </Button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ModalPractice;
```

I want to be able to get food name with the respective category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of filtering the whole array, you can add a new state in the component and store the selected food item in it and show that in the modal. Once modal is closed, you can then clear the state.

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState({});
```

Than you can update the handleClose and handleShow methods like below
in `handleClose` method, we can clear the selectedItem state to empty object.

```
 const handleClose = () => {
   setShow(false);
   setSelectedItem({})
}
```

in `handleShow` method, we can assign the selected item to the selectedItem state

```
const handleShow = (e, item) => {
   setShow(true);
   setSelectedItem(item)
}
```

and after than please update the click method to pass the selected list like

```
<Button variant='primary' onClick={e => handleShow(e, list)}>
   Detail
 </Button>
```

Please also update the modal code to show name and category from the `selectedItem` state.

```
<Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>{selectedItem.name)}</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>{selectedItem.category)}</Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant='secondary' onClick={handleClose}>
        Close
      </Button>
      <Button variant='primary' onClick={handleClose}>
        Save Changes
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
```